# using fstream object to store information from a file into variables

Tags: c++, fstream

I have the following block of code that i am using to read a text file of the following format:

```
firstname lastname id mark
firstname lastname id mark
```

Following is the block of code.

```
void DBManager::ReadFile(void){
fstream myfile; /*fstream object that will be used for file input and output operations*/
char* fn;       /*pointer to the storage which will hold firstname*/
char* ln;       /*pointer to the storage which will hold lastname*/
int id;         /*integer var to hold the id*/
float mark;     /*float var to hold the mark*/

/*read in the filename*/
g_FileName = new char[1024];                /*allocate memory on the heap to store filename*/
cout << "Please enter the filename:";
    cin >> g_FileName;

/*open file*/
myfile.open(g_FileName, ios::in | ios::out);

if(myfile.is_open()){   /*check if the file opening is successful*/
    cout << "File reading successful !\n";

    /*read information from the file into temporary variables before passing them onto the heap*/
    while (!myfile.eof()) {

        fn=(char*) new char[1024];
        ln=(char*) new char[1024];
        myfile >> fn >> ln >> id >> mark;
        cout << fn << " " << ln << " " << id << " " << mark << " " << endl;

    }
    myfile.close();
}
else{                   /*else print error and return*/
    perror("");
    return;
}
```

}

The above block of code works ! :)
But I am surprised as to how myfile knows it is supposed to hold one line at a time and how its being smart enough about setting the four variables.

I am new to C++ , and hence this might be covered in some sort of documentation. But i would be happy to have some insight from you'll or a link to somewhere i can understand fstream objects better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, `std::fstream` is a type of stream which works specifically for files. When reading from a file, the interface for `std::fstream` is almost identical to `std::cin`. Input streams are programmed to read the next word or number when asked with the `>>` operator. They know where words and numbers are because they are separated by white space. In the default locale, spaces, tabs and newlines are considered to be white space. You can change the locale to include other characters, like commas, and have those be skipped while reading from a file. Basically, when reading with input streams, newlines and spaces are treated the same.

Some nice explanation for learning about streams is here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the question is. However, the code has several problems:

1. You should **always** check input **after** having tried to read.
2. Testing for `eof()` to determine if there is more to read doesn't work.
3. You have a memory leak, allocating memory in every iterator.
4. Reading without a constraint into a `char` array is unsafe, i.e., it is prone to buffer overrides (one of the major attack vectors).

You want to use a loop looking something like this:

```
std::string fn, ln;
while (myfile >> fn >> ln >> id >> mark) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Dietmar,
basically i am not sure how my code works ..
is myfile automatically configured to hold one line at a time ?

Comment: The input doesn't really care about lines but reads the four values into variables and holds them. If the values happen to split across lines it would still do the same thing. Note, that the separators of your values used are spaces, i.e. you name forename and the last name can't contain any spaces.

Comment: thanks Dietmar ! i see whats happening now. Thanks for your suggestions... 
As its for a school assignment we dont have to worry about 1 and 4. But we have been asked to worry about memory leaks

i am calling a constructor to create a student object with these temp vars at end of each iteration . so there is no leak . as i pass the pointers to first and lastname into the constructor .. 

regarding 2. why wont checking for eof() work ??

Comment: If you skip 1. you'll end up sort of processing the last line twice! You enter the loop at the end of the file and won't read anything new which normally appears as if the last line is processed twice. With respect to the pointer, I strongly recommend **not** to use pointers but use, e.g., `std::string` instead. With respect to `eof()`: it may never get set if any of the inputs is invalid, providing an infinite loop. It is generally wrong to use `eof()` for loop controls. At the very least you would need to make sure that you skipped any trailing spaces.

Comment: hmm ok i see your point with eof() maybe i should check that with good()
i have to use char* .. not allowed to use string (school work !)
i still dont get what you are trying to point out with 1.  .. can u provide an example ?

Comment: You want to read the way I have posted in my answer: before the stream has tried to read data, the stream can't know what will be read, and, thus, can't know if it will be successful. That is, you want to test the status of the stream after having tried to read. The stream will set an error flag (typically `std::ios_base::failbit`) and the stream object will convert to `false` if an error flag is set. Using `good()` is nearly as useless as `eof()`, primarily because `good()` yields `false` if `std::ios_base::eofbit` is set. However, this flag may be set as part of a successful read.

Comment: hmm ..thx for all the info Dietmar :) ! i will definitely be looking into it .. !